# Import data in imported script using relational path to the imported script (Python)

Tags: python

Say I have a utils-folder located some place (which is added to PYTHONPATH i.e we can import from it) with the following structure

```sh
utils/
├─ data/
│  ├─ data.csv
├─ clean_data.py
```

and `clean_data.py` does something like (for the sake of example)

```py
import pandas as pd
def get_data(path=None):
    if not path:
       data = pd.read_csv("./data/data.csv")
    else:
       data = pd.read_csv(path)

    return data
```

Then I have a script `main.py` another place (outside the utils-folder) which uses that function:

```py
from utils.clean_data import clean_data
data = clean_data() #FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './data/data.csv'
```

I then notice that if I print `os.listdir()` in the `clean_data.py` file it uses the folder as where `main.py` is placed in.

How do I make the utils-function work as above? I know I can just paste the full-path to the folder, or create the path in the utils-folder like

```py
#clean_data.py
import pandas as pd
import os
def get_data(path=None):
    if not path:
       path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
       data = pd.read_csv(path+"/data/data.csv")
    else:
       data = pd.read_csv(path)

    return data
```

but can't we just do it relational in some way instead of having to create the full-path in the `clean_data.py` file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that `os.listdir()` does not use the path of `main.py`, but **the current directory of the process** (perhaps your bash commandline, perhaps the folder set by your GUI) that is executing your script. If you cd to the parent directory and use a relative path to launch your script (e.g. with `python myproject/main.py`, you'll see a different output. So there's no way to make "." refer to something other than it does. (Unless you first find out the path and then use `os.chdir` to change the current directory of your process -- which is a recipe for confusion and unexpected behavior.)

Just check `_file__` or `inspect.getfile` to retrieve the full path of `clean_data.py`, and take it from there:

```
import inspect
from os.path import dirname
from utils.clean_data import clean_data

mydir = dirname(inspect.getfile(clean_data))
```

Comment: I might've been unclear - I want to handle this in `clean_data.py` and not in `main.py`. Right now I have handled it in `clean_data.py` by `path = os.path.dirname(__file__);
      data =pd.read_csv(path + "/data/data.csv")` but I just wonder if we could avid that stiching and refer to other files in the same folder using `./data/`. I have update the question

Comment: Yeah, from inside the module you can indeed use `__file__`. So you have a solution (two, really), but you don't like it. Since you need to tell `open()` where to look, I don't see how you can get around this. As you have discovered, the path `.` refers to *the current directory of the process*.